# Cannot GET /profile in React Routing

Tags: react-router

Im fiddling with React routing and I have just two different components. When I try to render my second component I get `Cannot GET /profile`

My routing looks like this

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
      <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

but my /profile component returns the error message when I visit localhost:3000/profile

Do I need to put render them from another component, or what seems to be the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/` from `/profile`, it should work. You don't have to explicitly prepend `/` if it is already in the parent route.